# mysql INNER JOIN with WHERE. Need to understand what the code does

Tags: mysql

Table `2_1_journal`

```
TransactionPartnerName 
-----------------------
 name 1
 name 2
 name 3
```

Table `2_1_transactionpartners`

```
CompanyName   |  PreviousCompanyName
------------------------------------
 name 1       |   
 name 2       |   
 name 3       |  name 2
```

For example want to change `name 1` to `name 11`.

At first in table `2_1_transactionpartners` copy `name 1` from `CompanyName` and paste it in `PreviousCompanyName`

Next need in table `2_1_journal` change `name 1` to `name 11`. I think: change `TransactionPartnerName` to `CompanyName` where `TransactionPartnerName` equals to `PreviousCompanyName`. But I do not want in table `2_1_journal` change `name 2` to `name 3` because want (give command) only to change `name 1` to `name 11`.

This is my code. Found no errors. But want to be sure about what code does

```
UPDATE 2_1_journal 
INNER JOIN 2_1_transactionpartners ON (2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName = 2_1_transactionpartners.PreviousCompanyName)
SET 2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName = 2_1_transactionpartners.CompanyName
WHERE 2_1_transactionpartners.CompanyName = ?
```

`?` = `name 11`

As understand code updates `2_1_journal` and copy `CompanyName` to `TransactionPartnerName` if `CompanyName` equals to `name 11` and `TransactionPartnerName` equals to `PreviousCompanyName`

Am I correct? May be there is better way to reach the aim?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE IGNORE 2_1_transactionpartners, 2_1_journal 
SET 2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName = 2_1_transactionpartners.CompanyName
WHERE 2_1_journal.TransactionPartnerName =  
2_1_transactionpartners.PreviousCompanyName
AND 2_1_transactionpartners.CompanyName = ?
```

Comment: Is this code faster (faster execution)? Somewhere I read that better to use `INNER JOIN`